# .nrt 4.0 c# code database backup

Tags: asp.net

I want to create database backup file and want to save it on database serve. but .net 4.0 don't support SMO. Is there some alternate so that i can create .bak file of database?

Answer (score 0):

SMO and dot 4.0 are working together.

Maybe some other is your problem here, because in fact I use dot net 4 and SMO and I make backups of the database.

I remember that when I switch to 4.0 backup was not working for me too. But the problem was on the services. First setup [SMO](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6C3E9EF-BA29-4A43-8D69-A2BED18FE73C&displaylang=en) on the server.

Then check: requires Microsoft Core XML Services (MSXML) 6.0 , Microsoft SQL Server Native Client, and Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types.

If you can not make backup run, check the log, its tell you why is not run (there is log also on SQL server)

Also check that the backup directory have permission to write.

Well the bottom line is that SMO run, but need to double check some points.